# How add additioanl field to message filter in private message module?

Tags: privatemsg

As you know private message module gives drupal users ability to send message to each other.

each user can see his/her messages in message page. Also table of messages can be filtered by subject or participant.

I want to know is there any way to add extra field to the filters ?

Also table of messages only includes these columns

- Subject
- Participants
- Started
- Messages
- Last Updated

But I have added extra fields to message via "Manage Field"

I want to know how can I add extra field as columns to table of messages.